# How do I create VBA code that is associated with a particular worksheet in C#?

Tags: c#-4.0, excel-2010, vba7

I wrote a program in VBA a number of years that reads in files and builds a macro enabled spreadsheet.  It works reasonably well.  I am rewriting this code in C# with enhancements.  The problem that I am having is that the VBA code I generate in C# is put into a module, "Module1".

```
        VBE.VBComponent oOLE = null;
        oOLE = WB.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(VBE.vbext_ComponentType.vbext_ct_StdModule);  
        var VBA_Code = oOLE.CodeModule;
```

My old VBA generating code put the code into a sheet.  I cannot figure out how to put my button click service routines into a specific worksheet.  Workbooks have a "VBProject" property but I do not see an equivelent for a worksheet.  Below is the VBA code that I am generating:

Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Call SeriesToggle(1)
If (ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).ChartObjects(1).Chart.FullSeriesCollection(1).IsFiltered) Then
CommandButton1.BackColor = RGB(240, 240, 240)
Else
CommandButton1.BackColor = RGB(146, 208, 80)
End If
End Sub

When this code is associated with a worksheet it works flawlessly.  When it is in a module it seems like it cannot find the button (CommandButton1).  Out of scope?

It took me awhile to get to what I think is the root of the problem.  I think there are a couple of ways to solve this problem but I have not had success with either angle.  The first was targeting a worksheet for the VBProject or VBComponent.  My other thought is accessing button properties from VBA code in Module1.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to move my VBA code to the sheet with the following definition:

```
VBE.VBComponent oOLE = null;
oOLE = WB.VBProject.VBComponents.Item(WB.Worksheets[1].CodeName);
var VBA_Code = oOLE.CodeModule;
```

Unfortunately I now have issues referencing my buttons from my sheet code VBA.  I need to track down the real issue but I answered my original question.